# Accordion images not displayed - MVC - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var icons = {
        header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
        headerSelected: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
    };
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        icons: icons
    });
    $("#toggle").button().toggle(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons", false);
    }, function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons", icons);
    });
});
</script>
```

I have gotten a Accordion to work in my MVC site, but when I modified the accordion Jquery to include Icons/Images for opening and closing (stright from the jquery website), I do not get any images displayed. Am I missing anything? I am not sure where i have to reference the images in my code. "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e" I am guessing, is the image, but I have no idea where it lives or how I can download it. There is nothing in the jquery website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if you have Jquery UI's CSS file and folders included.  That's where the images for the accordion are kept, as well as the CSS declaration that tells your page where to look for them.  It should be as simple as getting it from the Jquery UI site, putting on your site, and defining the CSS.

You can test to see if it's properly included by opening the page, viewing source  and clicking the link to the CSS  (works great in Chrome)  It should open an actual page, not error out.  You can also debug via Firebug, Chrome Debugger, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I had to link two css files. It did not work with just jquery.ui.accordion.js file. jquery.ui.all.css is also needed.

Comment: If you haven't had a chance to play with Themeroller, I'd HIGHLY recommend giving it a try.  It gives you all the UI features of Jquery plus theming that can be changed on the fly....

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I looked at the themeroller. I understand that I can pick and choose attributes and then it displays the controls based on my picks on that themeroller web page. But how can I use this in my project.. is there something I can download after my selections.

Comment: Yes, the themeroller site will dump you to the main download page.  Do the download, then get into the zip it sends you and pick out the CSS folder complete with CSS Files and images.  Link to it as you were doing above, and voila.  You might first try an auto generated theme to learn more, then try your hand at your own.  Once you get it setup right, you just change the files and you've got a completely differe look and feel.